# What are the minimum requirements to get a secure WebSocket working with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket

When it comes to WebSockets, it seems the internet has plenty of ws:// (insecure) tutorials, but hardly any on wss:// (secure).  I've got an insecure websocket connection working fine with Node.js thanks to [Supun Kavinda's tutorial](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/chat-app-with-php-nodejs), but can't get it to work as a secure connection.

Here's the summarized working code for the **insecure** connection (fake ip address):

**File: js-index.js**

```
window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://3.00.00.00:8080');
```

**File: server.js**

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
var WebsocketServer = require('websocket').server;

var server = https.createServer(function(request,response) {
  function getPostParams(request, callback) {
    var qs = require('querystring');
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
      var body = '';
      request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        // Too much POST data, kill the connection!
        if (body.length > 1e6)
          request.connection.destroy();
      });
      request.on('end', function () {
        var POST = qs.parse(body);
        callback(POST);
      });
    }
  }

  if (request.method === "POST") {
    getPostParams(request, function(POST) {
        messageClients(POST.data);
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end();
    });
    return;
  }
});
server.listen(8080);

/*Handling websocket requests*/
var websocketServer = new WebsocketServer({
    httpServer: server
});
websocketServer.on("request", websocketRequest);
global.clients = {}; // connected clients
var connectionId = 0;
function websocketRequest(request) {
  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  connectionId++;
  clients[connectionId] = connection;
}
function messageClients(message) {
  for (var i in clients) {
    clients[i].sendUTF(message);
  }
}
```

For a secure connection, I have tried many things, mainly centered on changing ws:// to wss://, and including a .pem certificate/key in the createServer() call, like so:

```
const ssl_creds = {
 cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/fullchain.pem'),
 key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/privkey.pem')
};
var server = https.createServer(ssl_creds, function(request,response) {....
```

However, I continue to get errors (only testing in Chrome thus far), such as:

> 1. Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
> 2. Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received

*^#1 being the problem I encounter most*

I'm using the same ssl credentials granted by LetsEncrypt for my website itself - I assume that is okay?

In summary, most of the tutorials I've found either do something exactly like this, or talk about how something like NGINX is required to setup proxies/tunnels - something I am completely clueless on.

Can someone tell me if proxy configurations are typically required for this, or if I'm just missing something small/dumb?  Any insight at all would be appreciated.  In case it's relevant, I'm just cutting my teeth on AWS with a Lightsail PHP image from Bitnami.

Comment: Not sure what your asking.  https/websocket example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket#usage-examples.

Comment: The question is regarding secure websockets specifically.  The example you provided is for INsecure websockets.

Comment: Search on that page for https.

Comment: Also here https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/7db960ef47f9e87799a17e5a7ef3f46d3b1b9227/docs/WebSocketServer.md#server-config-options.

Comment: All I see is a brief bullet point that says "use https.createServer instead of http.createServer".  Which is exactly what my example code above uses.  Have you successfully implemented a secure websocket in node?

Comment: ^Sorry, posted this before your GitHub link came through (I'm on my phone so updates are spotty).  Will check that one soon.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking, because all you need is a working https server.

Comment: I don't really know what I'm asking either.  I just know that I haven't been able to get this working with wss://.  Also, the author of the tutorial linked above just commented (you can read it in full at that link) saying he had a similar issue and used Cloudfare's proxy to circumvent.  I will be exploring all of this over the weekend and will share any worthwhile updates here.

Comment: Have you tested that your https server works on its own with a plain https request?

Comment: The site loads and all browsers recognize it as secure, if that's what you mean? https://walbux.com